localization of a module at a prime ideal
I am reading Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra about localizations of modules. There are some questions I have met. Can someone give me some help?

The element $m/1$ is zero in $M_P$ if and only if $rm=0$ for some $r\in R-P$, so localizing at $P$ annihilates the $P'$-torsion elements of $M$ for primes $P'$ not contained in $P$. In particular, localizing at $(0)$ over an integral domain annihilates the torsion subgroup of $M$.

Consider the localization map $\pi:M\to M_P$, then $m\in\ker\pi$ if and only if $\exists\,d\in D=R\setminus P$ s.t. $\pi(m)=m/1=0/d\in M_P$, i.e., $\exists\,x\in D$ s.t. $x(d\cdot m-1\cdot0)=0\ \Leftrightarrow\ xdm=0$ if and only if (since $D$ is multiplicatively closed, $r:=xd\in D$) $\exists\,r\in D=R\setminus P$ s.t. $rm=0$. This is the first statement in the context.
But for the second statement, I guess, it says that $\forall\,P'\in\mathrm{Spec}\,R$ with $P'\not\subseteq P$ and $\forall\,m\in\mathrm{Tor}_{P'}(M)=\big\{\ m\in M\ |\ \exists\,r\in P'\setminus\{0\}\ \text{s.t.}\ rm=0\ \big\}$, $m/1=0\in M_P$.
Then $P'\not\subseteq P$ implies that $(R\setminus P)\cap P'\not=\varnothing$. And the statement turns into that if $m\in\mathrm{Tor}_{P'}(M)$ then $\exists\,r\in D=R\setminus P$ s.t. $rm=0$. So we must have $R\setminus P\subseteq P'\setminus\{0\}$, but how can we obtain this? I think it is not necessarily true.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ be the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the nonzero prime ideal $(p)$. Any abelian group $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module so we may localize $M$ at $(p)$ by forming $M_{(p)}$. This abelian group is the same as the quotient of $M$ with respect to the subgroup of elements whose order is finite and not divisible by $p$.

Consider the localization map $\pi:M\to M_{\langle p\rangle}$, then $m\in\ker\pi$ if and only if $\exists\,r\in D=R\setminus P=\mathbb{Z}\setminus p\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $rm=0$, i.e., $m$ is of finite order not divisible by $p$. Then $M/\ker\pi$ is isomorphic to a $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule (namely a additively subgroup) of $M_{\langle p\rangle}$, and it remains to show that $\pi$ is surjective so that we can get the second statement, but I also have no ideas about this.
